# c# array sent within another class sends back zeros

Tags: c#, arrays, class, oop, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a problem that I recently got stuck on.  I'm simply trying to run a program that instantiates and displays an object I have named HockeyPlayer.  I tried using it with an array size of twenty. Everything I have done so far seems to have been working. However, when I compile and finish entering the player data the list comes back as zeros.  I not really sure what is going on here.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace TestHockeyPlayer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HockeyPlayer[] players = new HockeyPlayer[20];
            int x;
            string lastName;
            int jerseyNumber;
            int goalsScored;

            for(x = 0; x < players.Length; ++x)
            {
                GetPlayerData(out lastName, out jerseyNumber, out goalsScored);
                players[x] = new HockeyPlayer(lastName, jerseyNumber, goalsScored);
            }

            for(x = 0; x < players.Length; ++x)
            {
                DisplayRoster(players[x]);
            }


        }

        static void DisplayRoster(HockeyPlayer ply)
        {
            WriteLine("{0, 5}{1, -10}{2, 6}", ply.LastName, ply.JerseyNum, ply.Goals);
        }

        static void GetPlayerData(out string lastName, out int jerseyNumber, out int goalsScored)
        {
            string userInput;
            WriteLine("Please enter player's last name >>");
            lastName = ReadLine();
            WriteLine("Please enter the jersey number for {0} >>", lastName);
            userInput = ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(userInput, out jerseyNumber);
            WriteLine("How many goals has {0} scored? >>", lastName);
            userInput = ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(userInput, out goalsScored);     
        }
    }

    class HockeyPlayer
    {
        private string name;
        private int jerseyNum;
        private int goals;

        public string LastName {get; set;}

        public int JerseyNum {get; set;}

        public int Goals {get; set;}

        public HockeyPlayer(string lastName, int jerseyNumber, int goalsScored)
        {
            name = lastName;
            jerseyNum = jerseyNumber;
            goals = goalsScored;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is reasonable question, please read [MCVE] guidance on providing code. I understand that building minimal example may require more effort and even solve problem without getting some fame on SO, but coming up with good small sample will likely bring you good answers and upvotes (large code walls frequently bring downvotes, but for most one-account-per-question cases it does not matter)

Comment: Just a refactoring suggestion, why not have your GetPlayerData just return a HockeyPlayer so you don't have to fiddle with all of those outs?

Answer (score 3):

You set your private fields in the constructor of the `HockeyPlayer` class, but you try to retrieve them via the public properties, which you never set.

Change your property definitions to:

`public string LastName { get { return name; } set { name = value;} }`

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Another option apart from other answer, remove your private `fields` and use auto properties directly.

```
class HockeyPlayer
{

    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public int JerseyNum {get; set;}
    public int Goals {get; set;}

    public HockeyPlayer(string lastName, int jerseyNumber, int goalsScored)
    {
        LastName = lastName;
        JerseyNum = jerseyNumber;
        Goals = goalsScored;
    }
}
```